# Lowering various input voltages by 1 volt

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

[Step-down buck converters like this one](https://cdn3.volusion.com/btfzd.umflq/v/vspfiles/photos/AD281-2.jpg?v-cache=1475058830) lowers various input voltages to a fixed voltage. For example 12V/9V/6V to 3V. But is there way to lower various input voltages by 1 volt, that is, 12V to 11V, 9V to 8V, and 6V to 5V?

Comment: Yes. Designing one is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: signals or supply currents?  if supply, how much current?  how much precision is needed?

Comment: @Jasen It's for controlling a fan speed, so I guess it is "supply currents", and precision is not that important: just somewhere closer to 1 volt should be good enough.

Comment: Depending on the current requirements, sometimes even using a couple of diodes in series does the trick. Depends on the circuit and application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there way to lower various input voltages by 1 volt

Yes. However, a buck converter will probably not do any better than a LDO in this case, and probably will do worse.

Here is a circuit that might do the job:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpG5JF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If \$V_{in}\$ is greater than 2V, and the
inputs to the op amp are within their compliance range, then \$V_{out} = V_{in} - 1V\$

The 1V reference voltage may be implemented in a number of ways.

Comment: Thanks. If I may ask one more, how difficult it would be to modify it to work only when the Vin is less than 4V? That is, Vin->Vout relation is like for example, 9V -> 9V, 5V -> 5V, but 3V-> 2V? That was the ideal goal, but I thought that might be too complicated, so I just asked about reducing the input by 1V.

Comment: That is really a different question. Try asking in a new question. I haven't thought about it, so I don't know the answer at the moment. Make a reference to this question in your new question and be explicit that you are asking something new, so it doesn't get down-voted or closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy enough with a fixed 1.25V you can put a shunt regulator in series.

Eg. [MAX6069](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6069.pdf) for 1uA minimum up to 1mA or so

[TLV431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv431.pdf?ts=1618826366505&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLV431) for 100uA to 15mA

Comment: Thanks. 1.25V is good enough, but is there a "Shunt regulator" that can handle more than 15mA, like 1A or something? The input voltage 12V was just an example, and in my case it is between 3.5V to 9V.

Comment: Not really, as far as I know. Suggest some alternative solution if the current is substantial.

Answer (score 1):

This emitter follower gives a fairly good 1V drop.

For currents between 50 and 220mA the simulation says 950 to 1050 mV drop at `out`.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsuRJi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I1 above is not part of the circuit it just represents the test current used to characterize it.

It's probably not quite as good as that in real life being subject to variations between different parts and also a kind of thermometer of about 3mV per kelvin and subject to self-heating.